# confusion regarding debt and debit

Tags: debt

1. According to it's  etymology, the term *debit* comes from the word *debt*, which means "the state of owing money.".
2. Among other meanings, *liability* is a contractual obligation to deliver cash or another financial asset to another entity. Thus, *debt* and *liability* have a very close meaning.
3. In *The interpretation of financial statements* (and other resources), the author claims that a *debit* is either an increase in assets or a decrease in liabilities.

Thus, a debit can be a decrease in liabilities (if not increase in assets). And some times, liabilities are synonymous to debt. The consequent is the following:

"A debit can, among other things, be a **decrease** in debt". I find this statement confusing in terms of etymology, is it  correct?

In contrast, I think that "A debit can, among other things, be an **increase** in debt" makes more sense as the two words have the same etymological root and should be positively correlated.

Comment: Questions on word etymology belong to English language and usage stack